# Is Fetching and updating in same web service operation symantically correct

Tags: wcf, service

I know that WCF or any web service platform does not prevent the developers from mixing fetch and update in same operation. What I mean is mentioned below
List UpdateDate( SomeType Datacontract)
Syntactically this is correct format an is supported in WCF. But is it ok to do this in service oriented world, also is industry wide standard to support this.

One problem I see right away is we violate the very first law of SOA which is atomicity but are there any other issues associated?

Answer (score 2):

It's wider than just WCF: any method that appears to be a Get/Fetch (i.e. by its name) should ideally not perform updates.

The classic Bad example is a Property Getter than alters the state of objects, thus introducing the possibility of unwanted side effects.